# error while starting drbd service

Tags: server, sockets

I am trying to make server mirroring through heartbeat and **drbd**. The problem is that while starting drbd i get this error : **error creating netlink socket.** 
the full message of the error is given here

```
 * Starting DRBD resources                                                                                                                                               [
    adjust disk: user:failed(apply-al:10)
]
<1>bind(s->s_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &s->s_local, sizeof(s->s_local)) failed: -1 No such file or directory

<1>error creating netlink socket
```

Could you help me solve this. here is the content of my resource /etc/drbd.conf

```
# You can find an example in  /usr/share/doc/drbd.../drbd.conf.example

include "drbd.d/global_common.conf";
include "drbd.d/*.res";
resource user{
protocol C; 
#incon-degr-cmd "/sbin/halt -f";
startup{
wfc-timeout 240;
degr-wfc-timeout 240;
}
disk{
on-io-error panic; 
}
#syncer{
#rate 700000K; 
#al-extents 257; 
#}
on server2{
device /dev/drbd0; 
disk /dev/sdb1;
address 192.168.56.2:7788;
meta-disk internal;
}
on server3{
device /dev/drbd0;
disk /dev/sdb1;
address 192.168.56.3:7788;
meta-disk internal;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i found the answer . In fact ubuntu server distribution come with a compiled version of drbd module. when you install the drbd utils you should make sure that the drbd module and the drbd utils have the same version

for me what i did:

1-fist you have to uninstall evry program that may use drbd ressources for example heartbeat.

```
sudo apt-get remove heartbeat
sudo apt-get purge drbd8-utils
```

2-then you should update your repository:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:icamargo/drbd`

3-update

`sudo apt-get update`

4-install the latest version of drbd utils

```
sudo apt-get install drbd8-utils
```